# Hibernate Criteria for Group By with where where clause

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to use hibernate criteria for group by clause with where clause.

like if I have an sql like this:

"select max(id) from Employee where age>25  group by trunc(created_date) "

Problem is that my created_date column has time also, but I want to use group by on trucated date,excluding time.

How could I pass truncated date in hibernate Projection while using criteria group BY.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
    String createDateInString = "26-FEB-20";

    try {

        Date createDate = formatter.parse(createDateInString);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

```
List result = session.createCriteria(Employee.class)       
                    .add(Restrictions.ge("age",new Integer(25))) 
        .add(Restrictions.eq("created_date", new java.sql.Timestamp(createDate.getTime())))
                    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                            .add(Projections.groupProperty("id"))
                            .add(Projections.max("name"))
                    ).list();
```

I think there will be chance of error while comparing date. Otherwise groupBy can be done using Projections

Comment: Thanks, but I have made some modifications to the question, Can you please help in achieving the desired output